# Did anything happen to "hubble-class" telescopes military gifted to NASA in 2012?

Tags: space-telescope

I stumbled onto [this news article](https://newatlas.com/spysatellite/22813/) from 2012 discussing NRO (national reconnaissance office) giving its surplus unlaunched spy satellites over to NASA (with a lot of caveats)

It's been 11 years since that point, so I'm wondering if anything has been done with that.

---

I remember there was a mission not *that* long ago that has been prohibited from looking at Earth to not reveal some spy optics quality - is that connected?

Answer (score 2):

[One of them has been used in the Nancy Grace Roman Space Telescope, NASA does not have plans or funding for the usage of the second.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_National_Reconnaissance_Office_space_telescope_donation_to_NASA#Potential_uses)

The Wikipedia article also states that

> the only prohibition is Earth observation, a condition of the NRO
> donation